# Why does trying to load a System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection config section fail?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

My App.Config (removing other stuff) looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Settings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration" />
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    ...
  </appSettings>

  <Settings>
    <add key="something" value="5"/>
  </Settings>
</Configuration
```

I have a custom config section using `System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection` as key-value pairs is all I require.
However when I try to access this with the following code:

```
var settings = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Settings");
```

I get an exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer threw an exception.
  Source=...
Inner Exception 1:
ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for Settings: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Inner Exception 2:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why can it not utilise `System.Configuration`? I based this on code I saw online, so if there is a neater way to get the same effect I am happpy to change it - I just want to avoid writing a custom config-section class if I don't need to.

Comment: Did you copy `System.Configuration.dll` to the output folder of your `.exe`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602765/when-should-copy-local-be-set-to-true-and-when-should-it-not

Comment: Try to add `System.Configuration` to project references

Comment: OK, it is a reference but it isn't in the /bin folder. Even though I am using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` etc successfully. Weird

Comment: @mm8 I obviously don't want to manually copy and I have no idea what that question is even _asking_ ... do I need to add a line to some config file?

Answer (score 0):

As was alluded to in the comments, the issue was that `System.Configuration.dll` was not present in the execution folder.

I discovered that when adding a reference to a DLL/assembly in VS, the properties includes a "copy local" option which causes a copy to be copied as part of the build, rather than relying on the installed framework version.

This fixed my problem. I do *not* however understand why I needed to do this. It seems a bad idea to distribute a copy of a framework DLL. I'll leave my wnswer unaccepted for a time in case someone else can provide something more comprehensive explaining the *why* rather than just the *how*.

Comment: How is your solution setup in terms of project, references and target frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Exception is due to this:
Line 52 in System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetImplicitType
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/TypeUtil.cs

If you delete assembly name, it will work because you will not have a comma in your type declaration.