# DLL reference not copying into project bin

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, solution

***Project A*** references ***Project B***, and ***Project B*** references an external DDL (restored using NuGet).  The DLL should get copied into ***Project A***'s bin folder (along with ***Project B***'s DLL):

[image: DLL References Copied To Bin]

In my case, when running ***Project A***, I get the following exception thrown:

> Could not load file or assembly 'PostSharp, Version=3.2.18.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The DLL is not being copied into ***Project A***'s bin.  All other external references from ***Project B*** are being copied across just fine, which is what is confusing for me.

`Copy Local` is set to true for all references involved.  Example:

[image: Copy Local Reference]

How do I do this?

Note: Using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Msbuild doesn't copy references (dlls) if using project dependencies in solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution)

Comment: Actually, a better answer would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043913/copying-a-dlls-dependencies-in-visual-studio?lq=1

Comment: I think this is an example of a well asked question :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The options that I found were to:

- Add a reference to PostSharp in Project A.
- Add dummy code in Project B so that the compiler would detect that the reference is being used.
- Add a build event to force copy the DLL.

I don't like any of the above solutions.  They are hacks in my opinion and will only make for a more unmaintainable solution in the long run.

I have fixed the problem by using a common output directory.  This seems to be a recommended solution by many.  I have also experienced much faster build times.  See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280751/what-is-the-best-practice-for-copy-local-and-with-project-references).

Comment: I also found the dll needed to be using the same version of the .net framework

Comment: In my case, one project used the Client profile rather than full version of .net framework 4. Changing to the full version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this problem it was because I changed a project's name, but did not change the assembly name - it was identical to the assembly name of another project in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some dummy (unused) code on Project B, making reference to the DLL needed.

Thus, the compiler will guess that it must copy the DLL into project A output.