# Cloud project to publish with Copy Local set to false for referenced projects?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, msbuild, azure-web-roles, csproj

I had a problem, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545272/dll-reference-not-copying-into-project-bin), which led me to using a single, common output directory for the built solution.  For example, all release builds output as follows:

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)BuildOutput\Release\</OutputPath>
```

I have also set `Copy Local` to false as this is not necessary with the common build location (it also slows down the build process significantly).

My problem now is when I publish a project to an Azure Web Role using the cloud project, only the assemblies which have `Copy Local` set to true are published.  None of the referenced projects' DLLs are published to the web role.

Thus I am getting exceptions such as:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyClassLibrary,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How do I get the cloud project to publish referenced projects which have `Copy Local` set to false?

Note:  I am using VS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non-GAC assemblies you reference in your projects need to have `Copy Local` set to true in order to be included in the package you deploy to the Cloud Service.